# nginx default virtual host overrides all

Tags: web, nginx, config

hopefully someone can help, i've been trying to set up nginx with virtual hosts but the default host always overrides any of the others that i specify.

here is my config file found in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.example.com;
    return 404;
}

server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 501;
}
```

and the `access.log` shows

```
*.*.*.* - - [30/Oct/2013:04:09:11 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 501 582 "http://sub.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36"
*.*.*.* - - [30/Oct/2013:04:09:14 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 501 582 "http://www.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36"
```

thanks in advance for any help / ideas.

Ant

Comment: I have this same problem.  Did you ever figure it out?